# Node js - callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, function, callback, typeerror

I have a runningService.js which does this:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(uuid, data) { 

  getEventLog.getId(uuid);

});
```

When it executes I get the following error:

> /getEventLog.js:35
>               callback(null, arrFound);
>               ^
>
> TypeError: callback is not a function
>       at IncomingMessage. (/Users/paulcarron/git/integration-test-runner/modules/getEventLog.js:35:13)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

What is wrong with my callback?

Here is getEventLog.js:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var readline = require('readline')
//var db = require('./dbPool');

//get file name
    var options =  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "hostname" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : "18080",
    "path" : "/api/v1/applications/"
};

exports.getId = function (uuid, callback) {
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));

            var arrFound = Object.keys(body).filter(function(key) {
                if (body[key].name.indexOf(uuid) > -1) { 
                    return body[key].name;
                }
            }).reduce(function(obj, key){
                obj = body[key].id;
                return obj;
            }, {});;
            callback(null, arrFound);
        });
    });
    req.end();
}

    exports.getDuration = function (callback) {
        exports.getId(function(err, id){

        //get file name
        var options =  {
            "method" : "GET",
        "hostname" : "127.0.0.1",
        "port" : "18080",
        "path" : "/api/v1/applications/" + id
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));

            var attempts = body.attempts

            var arrFound = Object.keys(body).filter(function(key) {

                return attempts[0].duration;

            }).reduce(function(obj, key){
                obj = body.attempts[0].duration;
                return obj;
            }, {});
            //console.log(arrFound);
            callback(null, arrFound);
        });
    });
    req.end();
    })
};
```

**Update**

I created a new file called test.js. Here's the contents:

```
var getEventLog = require('./getEventLog');
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline')
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');


getEventLog.getId("251cf1e0-019c-11e8-935d-271b24e13f18", function(err, id){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
console.log("ID: " + id)
//console.log("Duration: " + id)
});

console.log("ID Var: " + myId)



getEventLog.getDuration(myId, function(err, duration){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    console.log("Duration: " + duration)
});

getEventLog.getDuration("app-20180125065122-0007", function(err, duration){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    console.log("Duration: " + duration)
});
```

I hardcoded the uuid(`251cf1e0-019c-11e8-935d-271b24e13f18`) for the purpose of this test. When I run test.sh I get the following output:

```
ID Var: undefined
ID: app-20180125065122-0007
modules/getEventLog.js:35
            callback(null, arrFound);
            ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (modules/getEventLog.js:35:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

The 1st thing is that var myId appears as not defined. I guess I need to have something like a callback in my getEventLog.getId but I'm not sure how to structure it.

2nd, even if I hardcode the expected value of myId into the getEventLog.getDuration, I get the callback error. I guess there's something wrong with this too but I'm completely stumped with this one.

**Update 2**

I removed `getEventLog.getId(function(err, id){` and the associated `})` from getEventLog.exports.getDuration. Now when I run the below code I get the ID(app-20180125065122-0007) and duration. I'm still hardcoding the id so I now need to work out how to assign it to a variable from the first function in test.sh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get id get an id and a function but you send only id

```js
getEventLog.getId(uuid);//change to  
getEventLog.getId(uuid,function(err,arrfound) =>{
  //do somthing
});
```

Comment: As a first attempt I did this:

    child.stderr.on('data', function(uuid) {  
      
      getEventLog.getId(uuid,function(err, duration){
            if(err) return console.log(err)
        //    console.log(duration)
      console.log("teragen duration: " + duration)
    });

There's still some issue though. `teragen duration: [object Object]` appears in my console, on what must be a loop as a new line of it just appears every 10 secs until I kill the job.

Comment: it will appear every time your child have an stdout event as you attach this event... my you have a cron or a request every 10 sec and you there console log or something like that

Comment: No .there should be no jobs running.

I did some testing and will update my post though.